# Input Keyboard is not showing up when click on otp input in Mobile, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, chat, android-applicationinfo

`//Here is the xml code and i think so problem is with mukeshsolanki`

```
<com.mukeshsolanki.android.otpview.OtpView
android:id="@+id/otp_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:inputType="text"
android:itemBackground="@android:color/darker_gray"
app:OtpItemCount="6"
app:OtpLineColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
app:OtpViewType="line"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />
```

even i have given here inputType='text' or number the keyboard is not showing up when i click on otp input section.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add this line in your themes.xml

```
<item name="otpViewStyle">@style/OtpWidget.OtpView </item>
```

Then, add style attribute in your XML

```
style="@style/otpViewStyle"
```